Why is an article often used with (the) Rubik's cube, although other "name+'s" constructions usually don't use one?
As far as I know (being non-native and not having studied linguistics), you usually do not use an article before a name + genitive. For example, you would say "this is Harry's ball" or "this is the ball that belongs to Harry", but not "this is the Harry's ball". As far as I know, this also applies to fixed compounds like "Snell's law", such that stating "the Snell's law describes..." sounds wrong (while "the Snell-Descartes law describes..." is right because there's no genitive).
However, I found one exception to this rule: the Rubik's cube. Here, everyone seems to use an article with the genitive. Why? Is my initial assumption wrong? Is it OK to say "the Snell's law"? Or are there just a handful of counter-examples where the genitive is so completely inseparable from the rest of the compound that in these cases it is accepted? (In the case of the Rubik's cube, when I was first told about it, I didn't know that the name was due to it being invented by Ernő Rubik and would probably have spelled it Rubix Cube.)
[EDIT: There are other cases, where the name+'s acts as a modifier and where you can use an article, like "give me the Colman's mustard" or "the Snell's law that you are using is not the one I know". However, when talking about the abstract concept and not specific instances of it, only the Rubik's cube seems to preserve the article. Thomson's gazelle as a species would usually not use the article, while you could say "the Thomson's gazelle I saw yesterday". However, it is correct to say "the Rubik's cube provides an example of group theory", talking about the abstract concept. Where does this special usage come from?]

Of course I did find it with the indefinite article or in plural, but that was not my point. As described in the long version of the question, I wanted to know why in this special case (which turns out not to be that special, see the answer by "ItWasLike..."), one can use an article (definite or indefinite) before a name+genitive (='s)+item.

I don't agree that the genitive does not have an influence: compare the Wikipedia articles for Thomson's gazelle or Darwin's rhea with the one for the serra finch or the red-fronted gazelle. In the first two cases, the first sentence does not start with an article, while in the latter two it does.

When they first arrived in the UK, around 1980, everyone, including the news media, called this thing the 'Rubik cube'. It's only recently that they seem to have acquired a possessive apostrophe and 's'. I had this book - 'Master the Rubik Cube Easily' by Dr. Czes Kosniowski.

@Lambie I don't think so, then most of these Wikipedia articles would be badly edited, namely the ones for: Thomson's gazelle, Soemmering's gazelle, Grant's gazelle, Wilson's bird of paradise, Wilson's storm petrel, Darwin's rhea, Darwin's frog, and Darwin's bark spider. However, I found one that uses the article -- the one for (the) Darwin's frog.

@MoP  Unrelated to the question per se, and I'm happy if you don't want to say, but I'd be interested in knowing where you are from originally. I've been having conversations elsewhere about national differences (I'm a NZ er) and I felt an impression of perspective similar to what some other speakers gave. One of them was Swiss and another may have been Nordic.

German is my mother tongue, if that's what you want to know. Could you be more specific about what kind of "impression of perspective" you felt?

Since ‘Rubik's cube’ is a trademark, its usage (both the article and the possessive) may influenced by the trademark owner's usage (which seems to be usually but not always ‘the Rubik's cube’ on their web site).

The natural form of description for a multiply produced device named after its inventor does not use the genitive: a Faraday cage, a diesel engine, a Tesla coil, a Phillips screwdriver, etc. Probably, a Rubik's cube is more common than a Rubik cube because the former is easier to pronounce. I would still prefer the latter, though, especially in writing.

This is a good comment but I don't see how it answers the question asked by the poster.

@user405662 I think this does go some way towards answering the question. If initially both "Rubik's cube" and "Rubik cube" were common, then "the" being necessary for the latter might have led to it being used for the former too.

I agree with @EspeciallyLime. Thanks for this contribution to John Bentin

Multiply produced device?

@Lambie : A device is multiply produced if many are produced (not necessarily mass-produced). To identify unique things, the genitive form is used. The only exception that comes to mind is the Eiffel Tower.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Rubik's_Cube_manufacturers

Other examples: Halligan bar, Petri dish, Moog synthesizer, Henry rifle, Maxim gun, Tommy gun, Congreve rocket, Fresnel lens, Stirling engine, Wankel engine, Doppler radar, Graham cracker (not a device, but the same pattern). Additional counterexamples: Napier's bones, Newton's cradle.

@RobertColumbia - the 'Tommy' in 'Tommy gun' is informal for 'Thompson'.

In some cases we're looking at a Compound Modifier* rather than a true genitive - the part that looks like a possessive term is being used as an associated adjective rather than an indication of ownership : "what kind of cube do we have?", which is different to the idea of "whose Law are we using?" that arises with Snell.
Other examples include "pass the Colman's Mustard", Walker's Crisps, and perhaps Dawn French illustrates it best with Terry's Chocolate Orange.
In those cases, an article improves the comprehension by indicating that we're using what looks like a possessive term to further define the nouns cube, mustard, crisps etc., but it's really additional information.
[*Edit : A modifier that makes a compound noun, not a true "Compound Modifier". I should have linked to this instead.]

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A Rubik’s cube—not the —is a manufactured puzzle, a physical object. Snell’s Law is an abstract idea. As the name of a real-world object, Rubik’s cube is capable of being, and in fact is, a count noun: we can have a box full of Rubik’s cubes (note the plural with s), unlike, say, milk, which we call a non-count, or mass, noun. The name of this toy is comparable to the name Franklin stove, which refers to a variety of wood stove invented by Benjamin Franklin. We could not say, *”My father installed Franklin stove in the kitchen.” Instead we would have to use an article, indefinite or definite, depending on our meaning.
Compare also to the term Young’s modulus, which refers to
a property of a material that quantitatively characterizes the material’s stiffness.  Of course, here one would expect a count usage since essentially every material has its own value of Young’s modulus.
Excepting for when referring to a specific instance of the toy—like the Rubik’s cube my father gave me—the only other context in which it is idiomatic to speak of the Rubik’s cube is if one is discussing the object in the abstract, as in The Rubik’s cube quickly became a darling of Mathematicians because it provided such a compelling example of group theory.
Snell’s Law is unique: he gave us no other law. By contrast, there are three distinct ideas that each merit the description one of Newtons laws of motion. They are conventionally referred to as Newton’s First, Second, and Third Laws of Motion.

Thank you for your answer, which gives interesting details, but I don't think it adequately answers my question. Your example with the Franklin stove is similar to saying "the Snell-Descartes law", as there is no genitive. Besides, even though "Harry's balls" can be counted, you would not say "the Harry's ball", and even though Newton has three laws of motion named after him, you would not say "a Newton's law of motion". Thanks for explaining the difference between "a Rubik's cube" and "the Rubik's cube", but this was not the question, and I would have been able to tell you that myself :-D

Okay. For what it’s worth, we can’t divine what an OP does or doesn’t know; that can emerge only from what the question contains. In any event, I will edit my answer, both to better approximate a scratching of your itch, and to make it higher-value for those who may encounter it in future.

I agree that when considering only the "headline" question, your answer is perfectly valid. From just that, nobody could know exactly how to answer this in the best way. However, when one reads the whole description of my question, I think it becomes clearer what the main point is. (It is neither when you generally need articles, nor if they are definite, nor when you need them with names+item like in Franklin stove, but why/when you use them with name+genitive+item). Still, as I said, thanks a lot for your effort :-)

And a special thanks for the example with Young's modulus! Searching its Wikipedia page, I found "the Young's modulus" mentioned quite a lot. Still, I think that the main difference in usage is not that there is more than one value for Young's modulus, since I am pretty sure that nobody says "the Harry's red ball" or "the First Newton's law of motion".

@PhilSweet, the kind of precision I aim for in my writing. Thanks for the catch, I’ve edited accordingly.

If you're studying its mathematical property, you're likely to write "the Rubik's cube is a permutation group," and you wouldn't be referring to my father's Rubik's cube, but to a generic Rubik's cube.

No, @PatrickT , I would not say it is a permutation group. I might say that the set of twists of the Rubik’s cube under composition forms a group.

First of all, it matters to point out that the use of the definite article is only one option. The ngram showing the use of this phrase at the start of sentences (below) makes it clear that, initially, this genitive has been treated as expected, and that only progressively the alternative grammatical form gained currency to  become finally the majority form, but only.

As the phrase is used with the preposition "of" we notice an approximately similar  pattern (see below).

This is repeated for "solving (the) Rubik's cube".

In fact, after the conjunction "as" the definite article is not used as much (below).

Similarly, compounds such as "Euler circle" are used either with the article or without.
A similar fluctuation is noticeable in compounds such as "Euler line" (below).

It can be said in conclusion that we have here to contend with the vagaries of grammar, and that no particular reason can be put forward for the legitimacy of the use of the definite article. In the words of Quirk et al (A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, 1985, § 2.60)
grammar is to some extent an indeterminate system [and] categories and
structures, for example, often do not have neat boundaries.
Addition The not-too-careful information on the "of (the) Rubik's cube" part, above, can be made clearer. An examination of the "of the Rubik's cube" part shows that an overwhelming number of the entries concern the concept and not the puzzle materialized as a set of articulated cubes, so that the justification of "the" as pointing to a particular puzzle can be discarded. (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20the%20rubik%27s%20cube%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The definite article "the" is used as we use it for talking about any product, game, produce or item. Chardonnay was originally produced in the Burgundy wine region. The Chardonnay is a world-famous white wine. Pass me the Chardonnay, please. Where is the Chardonnay I put in the fridge? Have you seen the Chardonnay? Did you drink all of the Chardonnay? What happened to the three Chardonnays?! My wife would like the bottle of Chardonnay she saw in the wine cooler…

The Rubik's cube is a world-famous puzzle.
Pass me the Rubik's cube, please.
Where is the Rubik's cube I placed on the shelf?
Have you seen the Rubik's cube?
Did you take away the Rubik's cube?
What happened to the three Rubik’s cubes?
My husband would like to buy the display of Rubik’s cubes he saw in the shop window.


Thank you for your effort, but the example with Chardonnay does not exactly relate to the question about name+'s+item. I don't agree either with omitting the possessive apostrophe in your two last cases. In English, I don't think people usually refer to it as the Rubik cube. Languagetool e.g. marks it as an error.

The problem resides in knowing why, for the concept —and not in the case of the puzzle—, you find both usages (zero article and "the"). You consider only the puzzle as materialized in the shape of a physical cube.

You consider only the puzzle as materialized in the shape of a physical cube… @LPH the name of the puzzle is Rubik's cube (note the absence of the article), it is a physical, three-dimensional object. So, I don't quite understand your observation.

Oops, sorry the extra "s" to denote possession is needed in speech. The correct way to punctuate the plural possessive form is: "Rubik's cubes"

@Mari-LouA : The corresponding Wikipedia article starts like this: "The Rubik's Cube is a 3D combination puzzle". Of course Wikipedia is not the ultimate authority, but I think that when so many people can edit, it reflects the most common usage pretty well. And I think that in the article they are talking about the abstract concept and not a single item. Thanks for the examples of how native speakers break the rules all the time, but the reason that you give for saying "Rubik cubes" is just your opinion, while we are looking for common usage and corresponding grammar concepts.

What do you mean by "you don't hear the apostrophe". Of course you don't hear the apostrophe as such, but you do hear the "s" by which it is followed. And why I don't agree with you on this is that you just state that you omit the «'s» because Rubik's cubes is "a mouthful", while I would argue that pronouncing "Rubik's cubes" is way more common than "Rubik cubes". Note that I am referring to this particular example with Rubik's cubes -- I agree with you that people might omit the «'s» in other similar constructions.

In fact, you are right: not one single dictionary speaks of the mathematical concept, which is a problem; the problem of restituting to each of the six faces of a cube its initial colour by rotations of the faces and slices after an undefinite number of rotations has disrupted the initial arrangement with uniformly coloured faces. I believe that is missing in the dictionaries. (A software cube is a program that emulates and presents the cube in some form on a computer monitor and allows the user to rearrange it. https://www.kenblackbox.com/cube/solving/markctr.pdf)

@MoP I made a mistake with omitting the apostrophe, thank you for pointing it out.

@Mari-LouA , turns out it was originally called the Rubik cube, but that this might have changed exactly for the opposite reason that you gave: Rubik's cube is nicer to pronounce; the "double k" in the middle that might leave the listener wondering if it's a ruby cube is avoided in this way.

In English, nouns like cube (countable) require a determiner OR must be plural.

An apple a day keeps the doctor away.

Apples are good for you.

The apple on the table is green.

A Rubik's cube lay on the table all day.

Rubik's cubes make good gifts.

The Rubik's cube over there is broker.


an/a or plurals go with generalities, "the" is always specific.
abstract nouns (like wealth, goodness, poverty etc. do not require an article per se.) "Snell's law" falls in this category.
BUT, it becomes specific below and requires a "the".

The Snell's law you are applying there is not the one I understand.

In context, there can be a the, even for this category of abstract noun.
Rubik's cube is a set phrase for the man who invented the device.

Thank you for the interesting example with Snell's law having an article! However, I think that in the case of (the) Rubik's cube, the article has become so common that even the abstract concept often goes with an article, see this phrase from its Wikipedia entry: "The Rubik's Cube was inducted into the US National Toy Hall of Fame in 2014." I think, this is about the concept, not about a single specific item (that may also have been introduced into the physical hall of fame, but just representing the concept behind).

@MoP That has a "the" because its functioning like: The lion is a noble beast. That use of "the" is formal. Think about this, You can't say: Rubik's cube [verb] etc. Right? As I said, countables need something. Unless referring to a flavour, we wouldn't use: you need to buy apple. It has to be an apple or apples or the apple.

Do you think it would be wrong to say "Rubik's cube [verb] etc."? I agree that "The Rubik's cube [verb] etc." is way more common, but my question is why! With other compounds like "Snell's law" or "Colman's mustard" you wouldn't start a sentence in the same way (e.g. "The Colman's mustard [verb] etc."), unless you are referring to a specific "instance" of the described object or concept, as you point out in your answer. Thank you for this insight. In my opinion, it confirms that the Rubik's cube is a special case and different from, e.g., brand names.

You probably meant to write "broken"… right? I can't find an adjective spelled "broker".

@MoP Yes, I do and I already said so. I repeat: countable nouns require a determiner or the plural. It matters little whether a name precedes it. Colman's mustard is uncountable. Colman's mustard is great mustard. BUT: I left the Colman's mustard on the table. It is the noun that counts for the grammar not the name used as essentially as n adjective. Is that now clear?

No, the/a/plural Rubik's cube follows the countable noun rule. Rubik is like an adjective or what they call an attributive noun. So, it follows the rule for countables.

Why would you say it's wrong to say "Rubik's cube" when you are talking about the abstract concept, which is not countable? Thomson's gazelle as a species is not countable, although the individuals are. Where is the difference with the Rubik's cube? More precisely: why is an article often used with one, but usually not with the other? Actually, that's my original question (in a more refined version): Why do you mostly use the article with the Rubik's cube, even when talking about the non-countable concept of the cube and not about the physical object?

The( Rubik's cube is a puzzle which can be hard to solve. Rubik's cube is the name for this device which etc. See? John Smith is the name his father gave him.

OK, good example with the name. However, in this case you are not referring to the puzzle but to the name as such. Still, don't you agree that the genitive does influence the use of an article? Compare Tesla's oscillator and the Faraday cage, Simpson's paradox and the Fermi paradox, Darwin's rhea and the Galapagos turtoise (OK, this one's slightly different), Snell's law and the Snell-Descartes law / ibn-Sahl law (which are the exact same thing) or Darwin's arch?

Thinking about it, the countable/non-countable/abstract distinction that you make might influence the naming of the devices. Maybe that's why most of these multiply produced devices named after their inventor usually don't use the genitive. I don't think that this is in conflict with my point before, since directly above you still have a lot of examples, where only the genitive prevents the use of an article.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
